# How to check if dependency is convex, concave or none of those?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear, convex

Let as assume that we have a set of tuples of real numbers. Or, in other words, we have a set of `(x,y)` pairs. The simplest hypothesis (or assumption) about the relation between `x` and `y` is that there is a linear relation between them. We can even use a linear regression to determine what values the coefficients of the linear regression have.

But is there a way to determine if there is a statistically significant deviation of this linear dependency? Of course I am speaking about the cases when the deviation from a line is not obvious.

I assume that the question can be answered in the following way. If we have a convex function, (like square root) than a linear fit will give an underestimation in the middle and overestimation on the side of the range of x. Similarly, if we have a concave function (like exponent), we will have an overestimation in the middle and underestimation on the sides.

Is there a standard method to count (or somehow estimate) these under- and over-estimations and determine in this way if the observed measure is statistically significant?

Comment: Estimating the model $y\sim\sqrt{x}$ is also a linear model, so the more direct route would seem to be to fit both models and compare some metric of fit.

Comment: But $\sqrt{x}$ is not a linear function. Why do you call this model linear?

Comment: Estimating a coefficient for $\sqrt{x}$ is a linear model, the same way that estimating the coefficient for $x^2$ is also a linear model. I mean that it's *linear in the parameters to be estimated.*

Comment: If we have completely linear dependency and then fit it with a linear function ($c + k \cdot x$) and then with something more complex and general (and non linear) (for example $c + k \cdot x + \alpha \cdot x^2$) we will get better results with the second fit. But it does not mean that assumption of non-linearity is correct.

Comment: OK. Then we use different terminology. By linear dependency I mean $x + k \xdot x$, where $c$ and $k$ are model's parameters. I want to check if there is a statistically significant deviation from the linear model.

Comment: Whether or not the fit is *necessarily* better depends on what kind of metric you're using. It's well-known that $R^2$ never gets worse as you add predictors (in the extreme, you can get a regression that perfectly interpolates your points). But if you partition a holdout set, it's unlikely that the quadratic model will have low prediction error given that the true model is $c+kx$, unless $\alpha$ is estimated near 0 and the range of $x$ is not "too large."

Comment: So, your point is to try to fit with linear and some non-linear function and then predict out of sample, check the measure of prediction quality for both estimators and then, if the non-linear estimator gives better results, to say that we see non-linearity in the data? But what about statistical significance? How confident can I be? Moreover, what non-linear function to take (there are to many of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A structured approach to this problem is offered in [1]
More precisely the following hypothesis test of linearity is performed:
    $$\text{H0: The data comes from a model with: $\text{med}(y|x) = \beta x + \alpha$ }$$

You will find more details these papers, more particularly in section 4.3 of [1](http://users.ugent.be/~svaelst/publications/DRmethod_report.pdf) where the authors propose a test of linearity (the alternative is convexity/concavity).

If you have a vector of values of $y$ and a vector of values of $x$, this approach is fairly easy to implement. Check the description of the catline in [3](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.7597&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

1. The Deepest Regression Method (1997). S. Van Aelst, P.J. Rousseeuw, M. Hubert, A Struyf.
2. Rousseeuw P., Struyf A., (2002). A Depth Test for Symmetry, in:  Goodness-of-Fit Tests and Model Validity, Birkhauser Boston, pp.401-412.

## Edit:

You might want to have a look at the recent [conproj R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coneproj/index.html) by     X. Liao, M. C. Meyer. There is also a [JoSS article associated with it](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v061i12) by the same authors. Among other things, this package implements a (bootrap based) test of whether the function $f$ in the model:

$$y_i=f(x_i)+e_i,\; e_i\sim\text{i.i.d.}\;\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

is convex (concave) or linear.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Wright has a good discussion of one approach to understanding convexity in this NIPS tutorial from 2010. It's in the context of machine learning optimization algorithms where he gives a good definition of convexity about 3:57 minutes into the presentation with topic "First-Order Methods."

http://videolectures.net/nips2010_wright_oaml/

(Apologies for the absence of formulas in this answer -- which would help clarify things -- but I don't know how to integrate mathematical symbols into my response.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check. To get formulas, put LaTeX expressions between dollar signs. For example `$\frac{x}{y}$` will give: $\frac{x}{y}$.